# Conditional groupby and shift in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have a dataframe that looks like this, which store the order by order information of an order book. Type N = new order, D = delete order and E = execution. the same order_id might be reused.

So basically the problem is that delete and execution does not have a proper price as they should be inferred by the last new order with the same oid. Could someone suggest a method to achieve this? Thank you

**Input**

```
       type        order_id      price
0         N              10         99
1         E              10          0
1         E              10          0
1         D              10          0
0         N              11         98
1         N              10         97
1         D              10          0
```

**Output**

```
       type        order_id      price
0         N              10         99
1         E              10         **99**
1         E              10         **99**
1         D              10         **99**
0         N              11         98
1         N              10         97
1         D              10         **97**
```

Comment: To achieve what? Your question is not clear. Through what code is your input going? Is the output provided what you have or what you want?

Comment: @jpp - I think it is uncorrect closed question, so reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need `replace` + `ffill`, since here I assuming you have the correct order of your df.

```
df.replace(0,np.nan).ffill()
Out[758]: 
  type  order_id  price
0    N        10   99.0
1    E        10   99.0
1    E        10   99.0
1    D        10   99.0
0    N        11   98.0
1    N        10   97.0
1    D        10   97.0
```

Or we adding groupby

```
df.assign(price=df.price.replace(0,np.nan)).groupby(df.type.eq('N').cumsum()).price.ffill().values
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].mask(df['type'].isin(['E','D']))
#df['price'] = df['price'].where(df['type'] == 'N')

df['price'] = df.groupby(df['order_id'].ne(df['order_id'].shift()).cumsum())['price'].ffill()

print (df)
  type  order_id  price
0    N        10   99.0
1    E        10   99.0
1    E        10   99.0
1    D        10   99.0
0    N        11   98.0
1    N        10   97.0
1    D        10   97.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. First replace values of `price` to `NaN`s with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or inverted condition with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html)
2. Then `groupby` by helper `Series` created by consecutive `order_id` with  forward fill `NaN`s by [`DataFrameGroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html):